# Is Matplotlib's Axes3D plotting not intuitive?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I want to make a 3D plot for these 100 points in X,Y and Z axes. I have generated lists that I require for all 3 axes. I assumed that this should be sufficient to plot a set of points in 3D. However I do not understand the output. I appreciate any kind of help in this regard.

```
################################################################
# problem : f(x) = (e**(-(y**2)))*cos(3*x)+(e**(x**2))*cos(3*y)
################################################################

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
x = np.arange(-5,5,1)
y = np.arange(-5,5,1)
X = []
Y = []
Z=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            z=(np.exp(-(y[j]**2))*np.cos(3*x[i]))+(np.exp(x[i]**2)*np.cos(3*y[j]))
        Z.append(z)
        X.append(x[i])
        Y.append(y[j])
ax.plot(X,Y,Z,'o')
plt.show()
```

edit/update:  I am not sure if my problem is with the code itself or the way i understand 3Dplots, Should I use meshgrids to get a plot that i expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of matplotlib do you have? The [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#getting-started) states that for matplotlib versions 1.0.0 and greater you should create a 3D axes as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

rather than the `ax = Axes3D(fig)` used in previous versions.

**Edit** Following the OPs comment it seems that is the result of the code is not as expected, rather than there being some sort of error. The following code is what I presume is intended

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5., 5., 100), np.linspace(-5., 5., 100))

def zfunc(x, y):
    return np.exp(-(y**2)) * np.cos(3.*x) + np.exp(x**2) * np.cos(3.*y)

z = zfunc(x, y)

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

In the above code a two dimensional mesh is created (missing from the original post) and the function is calculated as a function of these two variables and plotted as a surface. Previously just a line of points running along `x=y` was being plotting.

Comment: Then can you be clearer in your question - why is the output not what you expected? What exactly are you expecting? I have added some code which will plot your function as a function of two variables as a surface. Is this more like what you are expecting? Note that it seems there is a problem with your equation, can you double check that?

Comment: Even when the function is plotted on a surface the plot does not appear to be correct..... I tried using your code but it has the same issue (There is no variation in the 3rd axis (z) except at the corners)

Comment: Try using `numpy.linspace` as shown in my edit. The function didn't look right because you had too coarse a mesh. For the function you provided there only is significant variation at the edges of the domain. This is **not** a problem with your code. See for example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Exp%5B-y%5E2%5D+Cos%5B3+x%5D+%2B+Exp%5Bx%5E2%5D+Cos%5B3+y%5D%2C+-5+%3C+x+%3C+5%2C+-5+%3C+y+%3C+5

Comment: Whoa ! , thanks :) I was expecting something like this -> https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/11Optimization/annealing/images/f1.png (
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/11Optimization/annealing/)
( I was assuming that my plot was wrong :/)

Comment: There is a mistake on that page: the equation should read `f(x) = exp(-y**2) * cos(3*x) + exp(-x**2) * cos(3*y)`. Notice the minus sign in the second exponential. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Exp[-y^2]+Cos[3+x]+%2B+Exp[-x^2]+Cos[3+y]%2C+-5+%3C+x+%3C+5%2C+-5+%3C+y+%3C+5